# List last charges in Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get a list of our latest Stripe charges received in order to match it with our invoices and customers.

Is there any way of obtain the last charges since a given date (i.e the last week)? I have looked in the documentation but I haven't seen anything that could achieve that with the Python API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to list charges and use the `created` parameter to filter[0] to charges made in the last week, like this :

```
stripe.Charge.list(created={'gt': 1527085810})
```

[0] - https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#list_charges-created

Comment: True! I totally missed it! Thank you!